# How to make a multiplication function using just addition function and iterate function in SML

Tags: sml, smlnj

I have two functions, `add` and `iterate`, in SML.

```ml
fun add(x,y) = x + y

fun iterate n f x = if n > 0 then iterate (n-1) f(f x) else x;
```

Using those two functions only, how do I write a `multiply` function that for example if typed:

```
multiply 5 6
```

returns 30.

Then building off of that I need a function called `power` that only uses `iterate` and `multiply` to raise the first argument to the power of the second. An example:

```
power 5 4
```

It should return 625.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the trick is to use `iterate` to help you with applying `add` recursively. Since `iterate` is a list-combinator that takes a function as argument, perhaps it is simpler if you go about this in a very rudimentary way: For example, you could define `add` by recursively incrementing/decrementing by one:

```
(* Written using if-then-else *)
fun add x y =
    if y = 0 then x else
    if y > 0 then add (x+1) (y-1) else add (x-1) (y+1)

(* Written using mixture of pattern-matching and if-then-else *)
fun add x 0 = x
  | add x y = if y > 0
              then add (x+1) (y-1)
              else add (x-1) (y+1)
```

Now, that's of course grossly inefficient and completely unnecessary because we already have `+`, but for the sake of demonstrating recursion on numbers, this is an example of how to progress with `multiply` and `power` (still under the assumption that we don't have `iterate` yet).

The general method here is recursion: Since the function takes two operands, use one as the "accumulating result" and the other as "counting variable". Because this is a simple problem, you can just use `x` and `y` as the complete environment for the function's task. In slightly larger problems you might introduce more arguments that work as temporary/intermediate results.

You can write `multiply` in a very similar way:

```
fun multiply x 0 = 0
  | multiply x y = if y > 0
                   then  x + multiply x (y-1)
                   else ~x + multiply x (y+1)
```

This function solves the task (although still without `iterate`).

(*This `multiply` isn't tail-recursive because the outermost expression (`x + ...` or `~x + ...`) aren't calls to `multiply` (since the call happens inside the operand of `+`). That may not be a problem to you, but if it were, you can't easily write `... then multiply (x + ...) (y - 1)`, since when we use `x` for the purpose of accumulating the result, any subsequent recursive call has increased `x`, which means we can no longer add `x` to... itself... because `x` means two things now: the accumulating result, and what needs to be added once per recursive call.)*

Any way, to get the last step, you have to identify what `iterate` has in common with the `add` and `multiply` I made. When you can spot the common denominator, you can isolate it and call `iterate` instead. I would like to fix one whitespace "bug" that may confuse your interpretation of `iterate`:

```
fun iterate n f x = if n > 0
                    then iterate (n-1) f (f x)
                    else x;          (* ^- this space! *)
```

Adding this space does not change the behavior of the function, but when reading `f(f x)` one is tempted to believe that it says "apply `f` to `f x`", which is the wrong interpretation. What this function actually says under `then` is "call `iterate` with three arguments: `n-1`, `f` and `f x`; because `n-1` binds less tight than function application, and `f x` *is* function application (which is left-associative), we add parentheses around them; this is not necessary for `f`."

In `add` and `multiply`, `y` is being used as the counting variable, whereas in `iterate` it is `n`. So the names and positions have changed, which means that a `multiply` based on `iterate` has to place the `x` and `y` in the right place. As for determining a value for `f`: How about the function that adds `x` to its result? You can express this function either using a lambda, `(fn z => ...)`, or using partial application of the function `add`.

Lastly, with `power` it is much the same problem:

```
fun power x 0 = 1
  | power x n = if n > 0
                then x * power x (n-1)
                else raise Fail "Cannot express 1/x^n as integer"
```

Since there isn't a good solution for integers, you either have to switch to the *real* type to express *1/x^n*, you can also flip the condition and get the case of `n < 0` out of the picture before beginning recursion:

```
fun power x n =
    if n < 0 then raise Fail "Cannot express 1/x^n as integer"
    else let fun go result 0 = result
               | go result i = go (result * x) (i-1)
         in go 1 n
         end
```

The inner function `go` looks terribly much like `add` above, except `x` has become `result` and `1` has become `add`, and `+` has become `*`, and there is no negative case (`if y > 0 ... else ...`).

So that means you can actually use `iterate` instead of `go` as long as you for `iterate n f x` find good values:

- What should `n` be? (Something to count down.)
- What should `f` be? (Something that performs the stepwise calculation.)
- What should `x` be? (The thing that gets applied in the stepwise calculation.)

(...all in terms of `iterate`; they may be called something else in the context of the `power` function and the arguments it has in scope.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I am new at SML and was hard core messing up the syntax.