# Power function using multiplication and iteration in Standard ML

Tags: sml, ml

I am having trouble understanding a method to implement a power function in SML using only iteration and multiplication.

my iteration is the following:

```
fun iterate 0 f x = x
  | iterate n f x = iterate (n-1) f (f x);
```

while my multiplication is basically iterating recursively

```
fun multiply 0 f = 0
  | multiply f x = iterate x (fn x => x + 1) (multiply x (f-1));
```

Power function would basically be an iteration of the multiplication of the same base but I don't know which value to decrement

```
power n f = iterate (mult n n) (fn x => x + 1) (power (n) (f-1))
```

which is definately wrong

Comment: Your question is most definitely a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63628870/how-to-make-a-multiplication-function-using-just-addition-function-and-iterate-f) to which I gave an extensive answer earlier today. Have a look at that one. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> power n f = iterate (mult n n) (fn x => x + 1) (power (n) (f-1))
> ```

So, when it comes to naming, I might definitely write `power x y` or `power i j` or `power x n` or some such, since `x`, `y`, `i`, `j` or `n` look like they're numbers or integers, whereas `f` looks like it's a function. So right off the bat you have:

```
fun power x y = iterate (...a...) (...b...) (...c...)
```

As for what goes into each of these three parts, ...a..., ...b... and ...c...:

a. The thing `iterate` calls `n`, which is the number of times to iterate.

b. The thing `iterate` calls `f`, which is the function to apply each time.

c. The thing `iterate` calls `x`, which is what is applied each time.

As elaborated on in [How to make a multiplication function using just addition function and iterate function in SML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63628870/how-to-make-a-multiplication-function-using-just-addition-function-and-iterate-f), there is no point in making `power` call itself; the point of using `iterate` is to hand over recursion to this list-combinator rather than use explicit recursion (where `power` has a reference to itself somewhere in its definition).